# Configure Windows Azure Virtual Networks to a limited to a network range

Tags: windows, azure, vpn

I am trying to connect the Microsoft Azure network to a 3rd party provider. 
We need to modify our access control lists to a specific host/ip.
How can we configure Windows Azure Virtual Networks to a  limited to a network range i.e. one IP address , 2 IP addresses max ?

Answer (score 0):

Only Virtual Machine endpoints provide the ability to set network Access Control Lists (ACLs) as documented here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-acl/

There is a proposed idea to implement similar functionality on Virtual Network subnets which has reached the "planned" phase. I suggest you have a look at this thread: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking-dns-traffic-manager-vpn-vnet/suggestions/3139676-add-the-ability-to-set-firewall-rules-at-the-subne